# Excel VBA automatically creating serial number with condition

Tags: excel, vba

I had already written VBA code to create automatic serial number in Column "A", however, I need to control it with a condition. In the sense, the automatic serial number will be written in column "A" by the mentioned code IF the company name is manually inserted in Column "B", how can I add the condition related to Column "B" at the beginning of the below code?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NewSerialNumber()
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Set lastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    If lastCell.Value = "Request #" Then lastCell(2, 1).Value = "ART/QTN001": Exit Sub
    lastCell(2, 1).Value = Left(lastCell, 7) & Format(Right(lastCell, 3) + 1, "000")
End Sub
```

Comment: `len(lastCell(1,2).value)>0`?

Comment: @SJR , could you please explain to me your comment ?

Comment: That would be added as a clause to your If statement. You are using relative references so `lastCell(1,2)` refers to the cell in column B of lastcell's row. If I've misunderstood please post a screenshot and/or provide further details.

Comment: @SJR,  I prefer that you insert it at the the above codes .

Comment: @SJR,  I prefer that you insert it at the the above codes . because column A" which is named Request # at the above code